# Why does Wade execute his own gang?

Tags: plot-explanation, 310-to-yuma

In the movie *3:10 to Yuma*, Wade executes his own gang members after they kill Dan.

- I have this feeling Dan has earned Wade's respect, but Wade executes his entire gang after they have tried so hard to rescue him?

Comment: He had to. After killing the guy who actually shot Dan the rest would shoot him down knowing Wade is the kind of guy who will do that to you. Plus, we figure he had a change in conscience and a knowledge of how to escape - perhaps he felt redemption would mean clearing out your whole past. Anyhow, he admits he's rotten to the core.